# Is a Unix group without an entry in /etc/group valid?

Tags: unix

Is a Unix group without an entry in `/etc/group` valid? A user had the group as his primary group and that entry was deleted from the `/etc/group` file.

Answer (score 1):

The system will be unable to resolve the group and when you list files that are owned by the group, you will only see its (old) numerical ID. In that sense it is valid. However, you can't set ownership to that group on any files.

Basically, your system won't crash and burn horribly, but some files might be inaccessible by some users until you fix their ownership.

Comment: In fact you *can* set ownership to an unnamed group. With GNU coreutils, `chgrp +1234 foo` sets the group ownership of `FOO` to the *numeric* gid `1234`. Other versions of the `chgrp` command might not support this, but the `chown` system call takes a numeric `gid_t` argument.  Group names are mainly for convenience.

Comment: This isn't GNU specific, most if not all chgrp implementations support a numeric group operand as it is mandated by POSIX.